# datetime problem after deployment of asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, datetime

I have developed the asp.net mvc 2 + C# application. it has create functionality in which there is datetime field. If locally I runs the a application it is working fine . but if i deploys it on IIS server (v 5.1) it, is not accepting date more than 12 (if gives 14/10/2010) will not work), this means it is changing  the date format at run time on iis as MM/dd/yyyy. But in insert code I am converting the format in "dd/MM/yyyy" by this line :

objRecord.NextElectionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(collection["NextElectionDate1"], "dd/mm/yyyy", null);

I checked the regional settings , it is same as where i locally running application (US cultured) .Not any exception getting out.Also I tried to deploy application on iis 6.0 , where it is running perfect. But on client side there is IIS 5.1 version available so the application must be run somehow on IIS 5.1. Is this date problem cause of the IIS version. How to resolve this issue ?

**Edited 1:**
                   [image]

I have code like this :

[image]

**Edited 2:** Hi again ! while I am debugging the application I am getting ModelState.IsValid is "false" ,while trying to insert officer information on "Create" Action . how to know what is going wrong in ModelState.IsValid ? why should it is getting "false" ? Please guide

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948743/how-to-make-this-date-valid-in-c

Comment: You are getting this error because your databases is being sent invalid dates.  The dates are invalid for the database because you have an error in your date formatting. ModelState is false because you are passing invalid dates into a field with a DateTime datatype.

Comment: You have, for whatever reason, a problem with the date formatting.  Find a sample that works, and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with IIS.  It is a classic database datetime formatting issue.

More than 12 gives you the answer:  there are only 12 months in the year!  So:

Do NOT format the date in the "insert code" to anything other than US format, as your database storage will expect the dates in US format.

I have seen this time and again with MS Access databases.

The simple solution is ALWAYS ensure that the dates you use in your Edit and Insert code have been formatted for US culture, ie, mm/dd/yyyy.

Darin Dimitrov is right about the Model Binder practice he mentions.  But the more serious issue here is a square peg in round hole one:  As Microsoft is a US company, their databases want dates in US format.

In MS Access, if the data input goes through a form, you are fine just relying on your PCs culture settings.  However, if you insert data using VBA code, you need to explicitly format dates in US format.

That is exactly what is happening here.

Comment: any updates over this question ? It is too important for all developers I think !

Comment: Lalit:  we don't have enough information from you.  Maybe it is not important enough for you to make the necessary effort?

Comment: Ok, but, one thing i got yet. i think this error is run time and i think it is thrown by Model in my mvc application. I am trying on my best but getting disappointment ! please guide .

Comment: This is not working for me. but though i am accepting this as answer, have no choice !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :(

Answer (score 5):

I've just had this error on my server and I changed the culture in my web.confg.  I'm in the UK so I put:

```
<globalization
requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"
culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

under the `<system.web>` node.

Comment: +1 Thanks David. This resolved my issue of mapping the textbox value on MVC page to the controller action parameter.

Comment: This answer resolved my problem, for me it worked when connected to the live database (hosted on azure) in Visual Studio but would not work once deployed and connected to the same live database so it couldn't have been a database setting.

Comment: The answer solved my problem, I was trying to add for en-IN culture and it worked perfect. Add this inside System.Web in web.config

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

  protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)     
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
}
```

Put this code in global.asax.cs file. Hope this will run

Comment: I have solved my problem using this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the [culture and uiCulture in your web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx).

Also it would be better to use default model binder and action parameters instead of manually parsing dates:

```
public ActionResult Foo(DateTime? nextElectionDate1)
{
    // no need to parse parameters
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try to look at your .NET Globalization settings in your IIS.

[image]