# how to make this date valid in c#

Tags: c#

i want to make my date valid 16/10/2010

if i parse compiler give me error at runtime. how i can parse it.

it is formated as Day/Month/Year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd parse it with something like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) if this is user input which may well be invalid without it representing a bug in your code.

Comment: darn, logged in 5 minutes after the master!!

Comment: I believe you could also do it by passing in a culture to `DateTime.Parse` that expects "dd/MM/yyyy" format (such as a UK or Australian culture). But I agree that `ParseExact` is probably better in the case when you know the *exact* format.